# Hostapd in VMware player

Tags: networking, wireless, vmware, hot-spot

For internet, Im using a dongle. With the help of **hostapd**, I used to take hotspot from my laptop.

I've one laptop which has ubuntu only. So, I can use **hostapd** easily to activate hotspot from my laptop.

But now, Im using ubuntu via VMware player.

Previously, I created one wireless network and then I used to run hostapd for the hotspot.

But now, in VMware, there's no such option to enable wireless network.

My config for hostapd are

```
interface=eth0
driver=nl80211
ssid=blah
hw_mode=g
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=my_password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

My run command is hostapd hostapd.conf

All these things worked perfectly on my previous lappy but not working in vmware.

I get this error when I run it.

```
Configuration file: hostapd.conf
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface eth0 wasn't started
```

Please help.

Ask me if you need any extra details. Thanx in advance,